# How to set the log file path for transmission-daemon?

Tags: raspbian

I would like to set `transmission-daemon` logging to a different file in order to spare the SD card. I tried to change the `OPTIONS` parameter in the `/etc/default/transmission-daemon` as is done [in other Debian based systems](https://askubuntu.com/a/398864/177437):

```
" Default options for daemon, see transmission-daemon(1) for more options
OPTIONS="--config-dir $CONFIG_DIR --logfile /usbtorr/transmission.log"
```

However, when I start `transmission-daemon` I get a permissions error message:

```
$ sudo service transmission-daemon start
[....] Starting bittorrent daemon: transmission-daemonCouldn't open "/usbtorr/transmission.log": Permission denied
. ok
```

Even if the file is completely open to everyone:

```
$ ls -la /usbtorr/transmission.log
-rwxrwxrwx 1 debian-transmission debian-transmission 0 Apr 11 08:48 /usbtorr/transmission.log
```

How can this made in Raspbian?

Comment: How about the permissions on `/usbtorr`?  That's an issue too.  Check `stat /usbtorr`.   It should also be 777.

Comment: Thank you goldilocks, that was the issue. Once I switched group ownership of that folder to the `debian-transmission` things started working. I am glad to accept an answer if you file one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to write to a file, you need write permission on it, but you also need at least read+execute permission on all the directories leading to it.  So for example, if `transmission.log` is set `666` (everyone can read and write to it) but the directory it is in, `/usbtorr`, is set 744 (owner rwx, everyone else just read) and you are not the owner, you will not be able to access that directory.  This is a little confusing since you don't need execute permission to read a normal file, but you do need it to read/enter a directory.

By the way, you don't need execute permission to write to a file.  So, presuming `/usbtorr` is owned root, the minimal permissions you would need would be 755 (owner rwx, everyone else rx) on `/usbtorr` and 666 (everyone rw) on `transmission.log`.

That presumes that `transmission.log` pre-exists, since without write permission on the directory, transmission won't be able to create the file (but if it is already there and writable, it could write to it, because it can read the directory, and write to a file which is writable for it, but it cannot create a new file there).  So the best bet for the directory is actually 777.